# How to listen for new data for chat like app using StreamBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, stream-builder

I'am trying to create a Chat app. All the messages are fetching from the api as list. Here the problem is it shows the new message only if i reload the page. I don't want like this. I want it like when the new message is added to server it should show on the screen without reloading the page(like chating apps). How to listen for new messages and show in the screen. Here i using listview.builder to show all the messages. I think that i want to use StreamBuilder for this functionality. How can i change this below code to this feature. The complete code is added below.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MessageScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MessageScreenState createState() => _MessageScreenState();
}

class _MessageScreenState extends State<MessageScreen> {

  List allMessages = [];

  TextEditingController message = TextEditingController();

  void getAllMessages() async {
    var url = '$baseurl/getMessages.php';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        allMessages = jsonData;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllMessages();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Chat'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 500,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: allMessages.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    allMessages[index]['user'],
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    allMessages[index]['message'],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: message,
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                     //Code to send message
                  },
                  child: const Text('SEND'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The response from the api is

```
[{user:john@gmail.com,message:Hello},{user:rose@gmail.com,message:How are you},{user:rahul@gmail.com,message:What u all doing},{user:rose@gmail.com,message:Lets go for a trip}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use provider state management and move your function

```
void getAllMessages() async {
var url = '$baseurl/getMessages.php';
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
  setState(() {
    allMessages = jsonData;
  });
}
```

}

to provider class and make a watch variable for allmessages use in listview.builder.

please refer provider documentation.